# Loading staticfiles and css files

Tags: css, django

Is there a way I can use the `{% load staticfiles %}` to load CSS files in django?

Variations of this don't work and this is obviously wrong:

```
<css src="{% static "/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Whats the proper way to load css files using this django tag?

**EDIT**

Here was my actual solution:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading `/` slash from the `{% static %}` tag argument:

```
{% static "css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" %}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, saved me quite a bit of time friend!

Comment: @JeffreyHaines You should accept the answer if it helped; please do not edit your original question.

Comment: Um selcuk, I edited with helpful information. Please don't edit MY question